# Using awk -F with variable return value 0

Tags: awk

I'm trying to collect hourly data for a specific date and using awk -F..using specific value works fine but wen I use an variable in awk it turns value=0.

### Can someone help on finding the problem with my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
set -x
cd /dest_directory
for i in {00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23}
do
A=`awk -v var="$i" -F"," '$1=="203" && $3=="7003" && substr{$6,7,2}==var {print $0}' 190116* | wc -l`

echo "$i, $A"
done
```

---

Printout received:

```
awk -F, -v var={00 $1=="203" && $3=="7003" && substr{$6,7,2}==var {print $0} 19011600010204.TLG
awk: cmd. line:1: $1=="203" && $3=="7003" && substr{$6,7,2}==var {print $0}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: $1=="203" && $3=="7003" && substr{$6,7,2}==var {print $0}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                     ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: $1=="203" && $3=="7003" && substr{$6,7,2}==var {print $0}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                          ^ syntax error
+ MCN=0
+ echo {00, 0
{00, 0
```

Comment: What do you think the braces are doing in your `for i in {...}` line ?

Comment: @Dominik, in my answer's comment now you have changed the question(which was initially to see why error was coming). In case you are changing question's base then it is advisable to open a new thread. In threads you need to mention 3 simple things--> 1-sample of input, 2- sample of output and 3rd- whatever you have tried to solve your problem, kindly do so in a new thread.

Comment: Also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- we don't have your files, so there's not way for us to reproduce your results.

Comment: Note the up-arrow in the output pointing to a character and telling you it's a syntax error. There is a clue there....

Comment: @ glenn Jackman  Thank you loot! This was my problem, my var took value var={0 , this was the problem. Now script works perfect! :)

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is more powerful than you give credit in your script

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{n=split("00 01 02 ... 22 23",keys," ");
           $1==203 && $3==7003 {counts[substr($6,7,2)]++}
           END {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print keys[i], counts[keys[i]]}' files...
```

of course if the keys you're looking for all digits, you can do it much easier with numerical ranges.

This will scan the file(s) just once instead of 24 times as in your script.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I tried your suggestion but it complicates my problem. I will keep in mind for other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing from `substr{$6,7,2}` to `substr($6,7,2)`and let us know then. Since syntax of `substr` is `substr(variable/current line,start_index,end_index)` so we need to remove `{` and place `(` in your code.

Comment: thank you for your prompt feedback. I tried your suggestion and now no error received but value is still=0: " awk -v var={00 -F, $1=="203" && $3=="7003" && substr($6,7,2)==var {print $0} 19011600010204.TLG
+ MCN=0
+ echo {00, 0}. value should be =1356

Comment: @Dominik, to be honest your question was about ERROR which you are getting so solution was given as per that. Now for code's thing you need to may be post a new thread or so, so that people will NOT be confused.